# Sorting of list Composed of array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

am in a middle of project , and am kind of stuck on the problem,

i need to sort a list in C#
the list structure is
`public List < double[] > DataList = new List < double[] >();`

now i want to sort this list on the bases of the last index of double array in the list

like

`2|3|5|6|8`

`2|3|5|6|9`

`2|3|5|6|5`

`2|3|5|6|12`

the output should be  some thing like this

`2|3|5|6|12`

`2|3|5|6|9`

`2|3|5|6|8`

`2|3|5|6|5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
// reproduce data
List<double[]> DataList = new List<double[]>();
DataList.Add(new double[] { 2, 3, 5, 6, 8 });
DataList.Add(new double[] { 2, 3, 5, 6, 9 });
DataList.Add(new double[] { 2, 3, 5, 6, 5 });
DataList.Add(new double[] { 2, 3, 5, 6, 12 });

var ordered = DataList.OrderByDescending(l => l.Last());
```

`l` would correspond to each element in `DataList`. With `l.Last()` you use the last element as sorting criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Also using Linq:

```
var tList = new List<double[]>();
tList.Add(new double[] {2,3,4,5,8});
tList.Add(new double[] {2,3,4,5,9});
tList.Add(new double[] {2,3,4,5,5});
tList.Add(new double[] {2,3,4,5,12});

var t = from element in tList
        orderby element.Last() descending
        select element;
var tResults = t.ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is some old school sorting without using the LINQ.

```
        List<double[]> DataList = new List<double[]>();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataList.Add(new double[] { 2, 3, 5, 6, 8 });
            DataList.Add(new double[] { 2, 3, 5, 6, 9 });
            DataList.Add(new double[] { 2, 3, 5, 6, 5 });
            DataList.Add(new double[] { 2, 3, 5, 6, 12 });
            DataList.Sort(new DoubleArrayComparer());
            DataList.Reverse();
        }
        class DoubleArrayComparer : IComparer<double[]>
        {
            public int Compare(double[] x, double[] y)
            {
                if(x.Length>0 && y.Length>0)
                {
                    if(x[x.Length-1] > y[y.Length-1])
                        return 1;
                    else if(x[x.Length-1] < y[y.Length-1])
                        return -1;
                    else
                        return 0;

                }
                else if(x.Length == 0 && y.Length!=0)
                    return -1;
                else if(y.Length == 0 && x.Length!=0)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can't you just swap the -1's and +1's to avoid the `Reverse`?

Comment: Yes, in this particular situation it would be more suitable, but generally I like making Sort sorting ascending, it seems natural to me since that is how native Sort works. That is the only reason.